# R: add alpha-value to png-image

Tags: image, r

Is there a way to make a rasterGrob-object partly transparent, so to add an alpha-factor to it? I'm using a logo as a watermark within a `ggplot2` plot by inserting a png-image (as rasterGrob) by `annotation_custom`. However, unlike with `annotate`, the `alpha` option does not work here, so I guess the image has to be changed in advance.

As a simple example based on what baptiste suggests in his blog, so far I'm doing it this way:

```
img.path <- readPNG("logo.png")
pngob <- rasterGrob(img.path)
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), geom = "blank") +
    annotation_custom(pngob, xmin=6.8, xmax=Inf, ymin=1, ymax=Inf) +
    geom_point()
```

The example above works perfectly.

However, typing `dim(pngob)` into the console returns `NULL`. Thus, the suggestion below on how to set an `alpha`-value does not work:

```
m <- pngob
w <- matrix(rgb(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3], m[,,4] * 0.2), nrow=dim(m)[1])
```

This returns the error `Error in m[, , 1]: wrong number of dimensions`

Comment: 4 steps, in this order: 1) read the image into an array "a"; 2) set the alpha channel of this array (4th slice); 3) create a `rasterGrob` with this array; 4) pass the grob to `annotation_custom`

Comment: @baptiste Thanks a lot, it worked this way! If you put your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: i only summarised Roman's answer; you should accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Straight from the [ggplot2 blog](http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/23537012922/adding-watermarks-to-plots) by @baptiste. You can adjust alpha when you create `w`.

```
 library(png)
 library(gridExtra)
 m <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"), FALSE)
 w <- matrix(rgb(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3], m[,,4] * 0.2), nrow=dim(m)[1]) #0.2 is alpha


 qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), geom = "blank") +
      annotation_custom(xmin=-Inf, ymin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=Inf, 
         rpatternGrob(motif=w, motif.width = unit(1, "cm"))) +
      geom_point()
```

[image]

Or if you want to have a single image:

```
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10), geom = "blank") +
  annotation_custom(xmin=-Inf, ymin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymax=Inf, 
    rasterGrob(w)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really understand the process of the creation of `w`. I added an example to my question. Simply replacing `m` with `pngob` does not work for me as I get the following error: `Error in UseMethod("validGrob"): not applicable method for 'ValidGrob' onto the object of class "c('matrix', 'character')" applied. Additional warning: In editThisGrob(grob, spects): Slot 'vp' not found.` (I translated the error text, so it might not be exactly the same in the English version of R)

Comment: @AnjaM have you tried following the example I posted? In your edit, you fail to adjust the alpha value (creating `w` is critical).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: When I try to create `w` by replacing `m` (from your example) by `pngob` (containing my logo), then I get the error: `Error in pngob[, , 1]: wrong number of dimensions`. Typing `dim(pngob)` in the console returns `NULL`.

Comment: @AnjaM I'm afraid I can't say what's going on without seeing what you're doing. Edit your question to reflect your comments here, please.

Comment: @AnjaM you need to modify the imported png image. Look at the example I posted carefully, you will notice the difference. In "my" example, I convert the object using `rpatternGrob` in the ggplot2 call. It could have been done earlier, but not before the creation of `w`.

Comment: I don't want to use `rpatternGrob` as I don't want to set a watermark across the whole plot area but just in one corner. The comment of baptiste revealed the mistake in my code. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @AnjaM all you need to do is replace `rpatternGrob` with `rasterGrob`. See my edit.