# Annotate on grob

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have combined several ggplots with arrangeGrob.
Now i'm searching for a way to plot a image over the whole plot.
For example a watermark which lies over the combined plots.

As the result of arrangeGrob isn't a standard plot or a ggplot object i cant do it the usual way.

Is there a possibility?

Comment: Have a look at [cowplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html#generic-plot-annotations)

Comment: Using an idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357926/r-add-alpha-value-to-png-image) to alter the transparency.. `m <- png::readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")) ;
w <- matrix(rgb(m[,,1],m[,,2],m[,,3], m[,,4] * 0.2), nrow=dim(m)[1]) ;
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(), ggplot())) ; grid.raster(w)`

Comment: or use the new [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=magick) package to add the watermark ex-plot-facto.