# ggplot2: How to add a watermark across the whole plot diagonally?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was very happy to find the R ggplot2 tutorial [Adding watermarks to plots](https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-watermarks-to-plots/) but unfortunately it doesn't work with my current installed version of ggplot2 (version 2.1.0). Yes I could downgrade until it would but I'd rather avoid solutions that break over time.

However, the final result I'm after is the same:
[image: Watermark across the whole plot]

Using the standard ggplot2 annotate function this is as far as I got it:

```
annotate(geom="text", x=df$Min, y=50.0, xend=Inf, yend=Inf, label='PROOF ONLY', color='white', angle=45, fontface='bold', size=25, alpha=0.5, family='Arial')
```

BUT this solution is not flexible enough because the angle has to adapt to the width of the plot which in my case is variable (depends on the number of bins) and will go from 45 degrees angle all down to zero i.e. when it is too tight to fit the watermark text diagonally. The watermark font size will need adapting to the number of bins too.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example, preferrably with different (extreme) situations for the watermark size and angle.

Comment: a few alt suggestions in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022504/annotate-on-grob)