# Overlay images and set transparency R

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick

I have two images and I want to overlay one on top of the other such that the top layer is transparent and allows the features in the below layer to show to some extent.

I am searching for this functionality within `magic` and `imager` packages but can't seem to get it done. Found a good example at this [link](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/16948_38af70d4c22e45df84a2fd69d8698d93.html) but it seems to be using some geographical packages (raster formatting) but the end result is what I want.

*Image 1:*

[image]

*Image 2*

[image]

*Desired Result*

[image]

Comment: Here's someone's custom alpha function. Might be of use. https://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-transparent-image-layer-to-plot.html And if you want to [do it in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357926/r-add-alpha-value-to-png-image).

Comment: Thanks! Found that previously but the results weren't quite what I Wanted. Using `EBImage` now, which seems interesting. Want to change all green pixels (incl. all shades) to blue which seems daunting, but we'll see.

Answer (score 2):

With ImageMagick you can start with "input1.png" and overlay "input2.png" with a particular amount of transparency. This command in *nix shell format shows the basics...

```
magick input1.png \
   \( input2.png -channel A -evaluate multiply 0.5 +channel \) \
   -gravity center -composite result.png
```

First that reads in the base image. Then inside the parentheses it reads in the overlay image and reduces its alpha channel opacity to 50% with "-evaluate multiply 0.5". Then it composites the semi-transparent overlay onto the base image.

In that command the overlay will be centered. Setting the "-gravity ..." and specifying a horizontal and vertical offset with "-geometry +H+V" just before the composite allows you place the overlay anywhere you like on the base image.

To use this command from a Windows command line, the backslashes that escape the parentheses "\(...\)" should be removed "(...)", and the continued-line backslashes "\" need to be changed to carets "^".

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this in R? Also, another add-on, can I use magick package to change one color into another? E.g. all instances of green colour to be changed to blue.

Comment: I don't know R. I use command line ImageMagick in *nix shell and Windows cmd. As for changing one color for another, IM can do almost anything you can imagine from simple to very complicated, depending on your goal.