# How to map a two-dimensional density plot onto a photograph

Tags: r, mapping, scale, density-plot

I have a two-dimensional density plot which I need to overlay onto a photograph. I can read-in the picture with the package `rtiff`:

```
install.packages("rtiff")
library(rtiff)
x <- readTiff('F01_screenshot.tiff')
plot(x)
```

The data for the density plot is a very large dataframe called `eet2` (see reproducible data below); the code for the density plot is this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(eet2, aes(x=X, y= Y)) +
  geom_point() + stat_density2d()
```

I can easily produce both plots separately but don't know how to overlay the density plot onto the photograph in such a way that *the density plot is scaled down proportionately to fit the picture*. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

**Reproducible data**:

```
eet2 <- dput(eet1[1:1000, 2:3])
structure(list(X = c(0, 177.378, 27.289, 0, 852.719, 0, 852.813, 
71.068, 0, 144.875, 0, 140.385, 21.598, 0, 170.325, 0, 136.746, 
21.038, 0, 146.279, 0, 141.86, 11.822, 0, 146.078, 0, 137.681, 
21.182, 0, 148.867, 0, 132.886, 20.444, 0, 146.129, 0, 80.251, 
6.688, 0, 141.08, 0, 149.789, 23.044, 0, 74.097, 0, 141.182, 
21.72, 0, 83.075, 0, 81.192, 6.766, 0, 849.784, 0, 153.96, 23.686, 
0, 78.374, 0, 142.782, 21.967, 0, 72.929, 0, 142.922, 11.91, 
0, 83.639, 0, 143.912, 22.14, 0, 134.809, 0, 142.826, 21.973, 
0, 132.7, 0, 85.876, 7.156, 0, 138.935, 0, 80.951, 12.454, 0, 
144.385, 0, 141.716, 21.802, 0, 76.768, 0, 74.406, 6.2, 0, 134.444, 
0, 155.341, 23.899, 0, 189.336, 0, 224.517, 34.541, 0, 207.46, 
0, 216.122, 18.01, 0, 204.552, 0, 208.524, 32.081, 0, 207.513, 
0, 203.162, 31.256, 0, 197.578, 0, 204.362, 17.03, 0, 195.223, 
0, 956.396, 147.138, 0, 201.969, 0, 224.989, 34.614, 0, 214.064, 
0, 140.374, 11.698, 0, 140.235, 0, 958.501, 147.462, 0, 141.898, 
0, 143.337, 22.052, 0, 955.901, 0, 954.965, 79.58, 0, 131.323, 
0, 223.214, 34.341, 0, 952.203, 0, 143.102, 22.016, 0, 935.525, 
0, 918.238, 76.52, 0, 123.337, 0, 127.93, 19.682, 0, 915.755, 
0, 128.336, 19.744, 0, 913.158, 0, 120.076, 10.006, 0, 911.196, 
0, 124.387, 19.136, 0, 911.631, 0, 911.389, 140.214, 0, 910.433, 
0, 119.375, 9.948, 0, 115.898, 0, 910.073, 140.011, 0, 915.461, 
0, 965.025, 148.465, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1125.565, 
0, 1074.389, 165.291, 0, 1061.611, 0, 1051.23, 161.728, 0, 1044.3, 
0, 269.733, 22.478, 0, 245.869, 0, 206.934, 234.525, 245.609, 
250.874, 251.576, 260.164, 262.974, 263.161, 269.25, 262.693, 
261.818, 265.634, 266.479, 266.592, 266.39, 262.751, 262.508, 
265.093, 262.666, 262.343, 1059.856, 1075.848, 1077.98, 1068.255, 
1065.442, 1065.255, 1071.821, 1072.292, 1072.355, 1073.788, 1072.572, 
1072.41, 1074.295, 1074.487, 1074.499, 1078.434, 1080.074, 1080.293, 
1081.104, 1080.014, 1079.869, 1080.261, 1080.181, 1080.175, 1078.568, 
1079.422, 1079.536, 1078.84, 1077.459, 1077.275, 1077.805, 1076.787, 
1076.719, 1077.199, 1076.045, 1075.891, 1077.362, 1076.663, 1076.569, 
1077.942, 1078.842, 1078.902, 1078.713, 1080.023, 1080.198, 1080.764, 
1081.553, 1081.659, 1081.946, 1082.445, 1082.479, 1083.987, 1084.113, 
1084.13, 1084.741, 1085.809, 1085.952, 1085.031, 1084.708, 1084.686, 
1085.901, 1085.266, 1085.181, 1085.513, 1085.159, 1085.112, 1088.024, 
1088.29, 1088.308, 1088.889, 1088.327, 1088.252, 1069.543, 1065.069, 
1064.472, 1067.409, 1068.075, 1068.119, 1068.377, 1070.019, 1070.238, 
1072.384, 1071.454, 1071.33, 1072.31, 1069.704, 1069.53, 1068.856, 
1073.986, 1074.67, 1075.824, 1077.42, 1077.633, 1080.095, 1082.62, 
1082.788, 1087.112, 1090.026, 1090.414, 1094.654, 1098.678, 1099.215, 
1103.801, 1097.674, 1097.266, 1110.129, 1105.4, 1104.769, 1115.638, 
1115.922, 1115.96, 1115.612, 1115.278, 1115.256, 1114.682, 1112.96, 
1112.73, 1063.573, 948.249, 932.873, 844.512, 834.23, 833.545, 
865.203, 867.402, 867.695, 838.499, 864.3, 867.74, 837.215, 864.187, 
865.985, 0, 760.653, 862.073, 861.199, 860.757, 860.699, 0, 861.681, 
71.807, 0, 851.287, 855.415, 855.965, 859.554, 864.523, 865.185, 
868.109, 873.22, 873.561, 845.881, 882.877, 887.81, 893.391, 
899.782, 900.634, 908.492, 56.781, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 319.09, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 696.905, 0, 704.008, 58.667, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 677.276, 673.676, 673.195, 673.45, 671.209, 671.06, 672.474, 
674.07, 674.283, 674.896, 656.33, 653.855, 678.654, 681.884, 
682.099, 684.933, 715.507, 719.584, 735.659, 1290.244, 1364.188, 
1362.632, 1366.322, 1366.568, 1371.973, 1364.1, 1363.051, 1361.383, 
812.325, 739.117, 734.716, 1322.199, 1361.365, 730.422, 731.132, 
731.227, 729.084, 724.164, 723.507, 726.199, 725.939, 725.922, 
725.437, 1278.917, 1352.714, 726.791, 1281.431, 1355.383, 1366.558, 
764.435, 724.294, 725.46, 724.544, 724.422, 724.178, 1288.932, 
1364.232, 723.902, 680.495, 677.601, 724.172, 722.856, 722.681, 
735.236, 743.706, 744.835, 554.779, 735.387, 747.427, 724.914, 
720.25, 719.628, 721.122, 742.971, 745.884, 742.171, 737.947, 
737.665, 729.207, 808.032, 818.542, 905.216, 106.496, 0, 1169.534, 
0, 1195.852, 99.654, 0, 1236.396, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1190.473, 183.15, 
0, 1143.686, 1132.754, 1132.025, 1123.856, 1103.6, 1100.9, 1083.716, 
1079.191, 1078.588, 1083.785, 1070.395, 1069.503, 1066.885, 1065.121, 
1064.885, 1064.401, 1065.285, 1065.403, 1075.009, 1076.036, 1076.105, 
1086.308, 1075.821, 1074.423, 1073.282, 126.268, 0, 1092.281, 
0, 1019.684, 1087.663, 286.389, 33.693, 0, 1117.064, 0, 1114.254, 
171.424, 0, 1111.518, 0, 1110.347, 92.529, 0, 1077.293, 0, 1107.754, 
170.424, 0, 1107.136, 0, 1076.571, 165.626, 0, 1067.475, 0, 1110.71, 
92.559, 0, 274.852, 0, 280.654, 43.177, 0, 280.278, 271.773, 
270.639, 0, 1060.434, 88.369, 0, 1054.964, 1047.876, 1046.931, 
1052.977, 1064.93, 1066.524, 1061.181, 1069.339, 1069.883, 275.888, 
970.662, 1063.299, 268.308, 974.232, 1068.355, 1044.757, 1065.286, 
1066.655, 1076.68, 1085.54, 1086.721, 1088.216, 1083.409, 1082.768, 
1087.272, 1087.283, 1087.283, 1086.689, 1087.19, 1087.257, 1089.988, 
1087.837, 1087.55, 272.953, 1040.007, 1091.144, 1076.712, 1089.387, 
1091.077, 1103.104, -360.56, -555.715, 1072.081, 1073.131, 1073.201, 
1073.04, 1089.257, 1091.419, 1072.888, 1073.111, 1073.141, 1104.182, 
1075.399, 1073.48, 1103.711, 1076.133, 1072.456, 1104.247, 1105.181, 
1105.305, 1072.744, 1104.02, 1106.105, 1074.673, 1102.759, 1106.503, 
1076.082, 1104.401, 1108.177, 1078.025, 1109.772, 1111.888, 288.949, 
292.278, 292.722, 1112.981, 1123.139, 1124.493, 1127.996, 1134.943, 
1135.406, 1136.071, 1141.749, 1142.506, 1148.754, 1150.764, 1151.032, 
1156.093, 1154.597, 1154.497, 1150.481, 1124.218, 1120.716, 1108.646, 
1095.181, 1093.385, 1113.175, 1089.783, 1088.224, 1719.795, -286.164, 
-553.625, 1112.49, 1099.064, 1097.274, 1106.601, 1105.705, 1105.645, 
1100.75, 1110.143, 1111.395, 1114.044, 1108.662, 1107.944, 1115.615, 
1114.492, 1114.417, 296.606, 1011.559, 1106.886, 213.15, 735.037, 
804.622, 643.816, 590.868, 587.338, 588.443, 591.022, 591.366, 
595.437, 598.575, 598.994, -70.23, 562.977, 605.191, 608.988, 
14.755, -64.476, -86.326, 490.189, 567.057, 573.015, 572.841, 
572.83, 576.607, 578.243, 578.461, 579.714, 1343.595, 1445.446, 
585.277, 588.153, 588.345, 588.809, 588.843, 588.848, 592.898, 
591.447, 591.254, 592.538, 589.623, 589.429, 590.233, 587.901, 
587.59, 589.276, 603.526, 605.426, 691.889, 810.649, 818.566, 
889.948, 866.466, 863.335, 164.367, 164.895, 164.966, 158.056, 
851.73, 897.975, 164.51, 806.786, 892.423, 894.069, 892.465, 
892.251, 153.408, 842.909, 888.876, 151.935, 802.889, 889.683, 
154.817, 146.446, 145.329, 888.428, 193.529, 147.202, 885.088, 
224.817, 136.78, 147.255, 802.581, 889.958, 888.64, 889.975, 
890.064, 1575.971, 968.922, 887.982, 889.232, 860.991, 857.226, 
872.007, 893.987, 895.452, 859.373, 892.292, 896.681, 859.84, 
859.942, 859.955, 898.274, 860.41, 857.885, 879.17, 862.76, 860.572, 
856.434, 854.683, 854.45, 851.949, 174.027, 128.832, 848.35, 
847.791, 847.716, 847.847, 849.008, 849.163, 133.198, 806.744, 
851.647, 146.291, 773.622, 857.267, 860.622, 834.937, 831.512, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 623.517, 0, 631.712, 97.187, 
0, 631.526, 0, 641.912, 98.756, 0, 648.161, 0, 654.673, 54.556, 
0, 659.733, 0, 603.775, 684.278, 696.548, 689.181, 688.198, 687.25, 
682.216, 681.881, 711.089, 713.482, 713.802, 713.969, 715.124, 
715.278, 711.369, 709.299, 709.162, 679.428, 675.016, 674.428, 
675.948, 673.724, 673.427, 675.195, 678.8, 679.041, 681.486, 
686.341, 686.988, 696.445, 694.867, 694.657, 703.31, 705.003, 
705.116, 0, 711.882, 109.52, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1269.549, 1438.822, 0, 720.784, 60.065, 0, 721.678, 0, 713.535, 
109.775, 0, 709.244, 0, 681.534, 104.851, 0, 693.092, 0, 681.394, 
56.783, 0, 679.538, 0, 680.866, 104.749, 0, 675.661, 0, 668.345, 
102.822, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -69.364, -10.671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 677.983, 0), Y = c(0, -560.914, 
-86.294, 0, 12.57, 0, 10.336, 0.861, 0, -569.851, 0, -582.641, 
-89.637, 0, -513.461, 0, -582.556, -89.624, 0, -567.846, 0, -574.869, 
-47.906, 0, -567.25, 0, -571.902, -87.985, 0, -554.095, 0, -574.651, 
-88.408, 0, -557.127, 0, -365.662, -30.472, 0, -565.123, 0, -564.378, 
-86.827, 0, -380.282, 0, -587.338, -90.36, 0, -373.494, 0, -394.186, 
-32.849, 0, -15.305, 0, -586.833, -90.282, 0, -391.571, 0, -603.611, 
-92.863, 0, -392.659, 0, -595.738, -49.645, 0, -369.805, 0, -585.56, 
-90.086, 0, -607.653, 0, -598.77, -92.118, 0, -603.821, 0, -362.726, 
-30.227, 0, -590.569, 0, -365.806, -56.278, 0, -584.274, 0, -594.203, 
-91.416, 0, -378.246, 0, -385.426, -32.119, 0, -585.678, 0, -569.332, 
-87.589, 0, -572.327, 0, -566.971, -87.226, 0, -586.06, 0, -584.482, 
-48.707, 0, -593.944, 0, -583.298, -89.738, 0, -580.776, 0, -590.48, 
-90.843, 0, -600.616, 0, -598.535, -49.878, 0, -602.826, 0, -29.44, 
-4.529, 0, -618.062, 0, -592.995, -91.23, 0, -609.041, 0, -411.878, 
-34.323, 0, -413.262, 0, -52.608, -8.094, 0, -411.569, 0, -415.928, 
-63.989, 0, -48.63, 0, -47.12, -3.927, 0, -415.299, 0, -599.916, 
-92.295, 0, -44.314, 0, -411.139, -63.252, 0, -46.124, 0, -48.509, 
-4.042, 0, -407.485, 0, -413.499, -63.615, 0, -55.391, 0, -415.922, 
-63.988, 0, -57.45, 0, -422.827, -35.236, 0, -54.607, 0, -414.86, 
-63.825, 0, -51.45, 0, -48.986, -7.536, 0, -45.942, 0, -413.839, 
-34.487, 0, -411.075, 0, -38.956, -5.993, 0, -14.525, 0, 35.454, 
5.455, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 279.172, 0, 315.145, 
48.484, 0, 313.523, 0, 314.854, 48.439, 0, 314.166, 0, -89.369, 
-7.447, 0, -125.57, 0, -138.883, -157.401, -162.487, -158.14, 
-157.561, -171.662, -160.906, -160.189, -166.883, -171.154, -171.724, 
-187.379, -175.901, -174.37, -188.734, -185.215, -184.98, -189.818, 
-189.088, -188.991, 283.22, 302.83, 305.444, 270.066, 289.663, 
290.969, 275.119, 276.953, 277.198, 260.347, 261.677, 261.855, 
246.632, 250.916, 251.202, 238.808, 246.008, 246.968, 240.285, 
253.356, 255.099, 251.122, 262.086, 262.817, 258.677, 268.433, 
269.734, 264.812, 273.771, 274.966, 268.696, 276.112, 276.606, 
268.26, 275.135, 276.051, 265.545, 272.265, 273.161, 264.077, 
268.116, 268.385, 261.015, 266.217, 266.911, 259.724, 265.892, 
266.714, 259.602, 265.93, 266.352, 258.209, 265.537, 266.514, 
259.411, 265.687, 266.523, 259.761, 266.978, 267.459, 260.97, 
268.01, 268.949, 262.4, 271.867, 273.13, 264.803, 273.569, 274.153, 
266.979, 275.25, 276.353, 268.073, 274.926, 275.84, 269.625, 
279.424, 280.077, 271.785, 281.741, 283.068, 276.083, 284.162, 
285.239, 279.865, 291.741, 292.533, 291.52, 302.124, 303.538, 
300.685, 313.141, 314.802, 313.594, 327.048, 327.945, 325.593, 
339.796, 341.69, 341.58, 355.702, 357.585, 356.602, 381.738, 
383.413, 370.869, 394.752, 397.936, 391.659, 409.376, 411.739, 
415.584, 433.281, 434.461, 437.478, 454.368, 456.62, 445.173, 
427.865, 425.558, 383.004, 370.373, 369.531, 382.343, 399.016, 
401.239, 413.831, 422.157, 423.267, 432.015, 448.845, 449.967, 
0, 425.956, 482.75, 487.1, 501.178, 503.055, 0, 508.065, 42.339, 
0, 492.242, 494.125, 494.376, 484.667, 484.368, 484.328, 467.742, 
464.267, 464.035, 468.697, 433.854, 429.208, 400.85, 393.727, 
392.777, 376.735, 23.546, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 885.955, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500.323, 0, 481.941, 40.162, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
530.014, 516.432, 514.621, 494.618, 478.341, 477.256, 456.114, 
458.922, 459.297, 456.514, 425.5, 421.365, 462.707, 472.408, 
473.055, 467.768, 454.51, 452.742, 441.741, 201.307, 169.249, 
167.631, 163.795, 163.539, 160.509, 161.775, 161.943, 161.298, 
397.997, 429.557, 419.546, 177.979, 161.875, 418.022, 423.34, 
424.049, 413.55, 419.645, 420.457, 407.472, 415.496, 416.031, 
407.006, 148.509, 114.042, 409.442, 164.128, 131.419, 109.849, 
407.293, 427.122, 418.844, 426.465, 427.481, 417.779, 161.317, 
127.123, 409.12, 367.918, 365.171, 395.673, 396.298, 396.381, 
388.306, 392.859, 393.466, 473.545, 400.213, 395.325, 366.771, 
370.934, 371.489, 339.469, 387.501, 393.905, 386.022, 390.883, 
391.207, 378.721, 394.352, 396.436, 384.581, 45.245, 0, 380.042, 
0, 375.485, 31.29, 0, 335.187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 323.048, 49.7, 0, 
359.169, 361.068, 361.195, 348.111, 362.176, 364.051, 383.932, 
392.518, 393.663, 349.699, 392.668, 395.532, 391.36, 396.741, 
397.458, 387.906, 391.383, 391.846, 371.849, 378.048, 378.461, 
318.908, 357.694, 362.865, 342.973, 40.35, 0, 288.149, 0, 259.291, 
276.577, -102.466, -12.055, 0, 241.977, 0, 234.288, 36.044, 0, 
247.849, 0, 244.967, 20.414, 0, 290.17, 0, 258.996, 39.846, 0, 
269.854, 0, 259.002, 39.847, 0, 297.18, 0, 266.569, 22.214, 0, 
-87.029, 0, -89.617, -13.787, 0, -95.348, -79.043, -76.869, 0, 
246.968, 20.581, 0, 272.257, 289.812, 292.152, 271.933, 287.652, 
289.748, 276.443, 284.481, 285.017, -116.323, 230.711, 276.983, 
-141.084, 229.411, 278.81, 314.961, 280.304, 277.994, 277.686, 
282.62, 283.278, 287.306, 282.107, 281.414, 290.288, 291.936, 
292.045, 288.296, 302.772, 304.702, 292.15, 302.242, 303.588, 
-136.669, 270.271, 297.4, 274.154, 301.517, 305.165, 290.369, 
-426.184, -521.724, 321.366, 329.046, 329.558, 321.7, 306.849, 
304.869, 321.009, 327.981, 328.91, 290.339, 328.378, 330.914, 
289.022, 325.172, 329.992, 288.447, 295.19, 296.089, 322.57, 
298.091, 296.459, 321.394, 300.861, 298.123, 320.881, 300.679, 
297.985, 319.966, 296.464, 294.897, -164.893, -160.079, -159.437, 
278.924, 281.357, 281.682, 269.259, 274.752, 275.118, 267.165, 
265.143, 264.873, 258.509, 264.614, 265.429, 256.744, 266.259, 
266.893, 263.361, 301.473, 306.555, 262.416, 313.245, 320.022, 
281.712, 320.535, 323.123, -194.846, -521.034, -564.526, 274.367, 
278.267, 278.787, 264.133, 268.555, 268.85, 256.818, 266.194, 
267.444, 260.084, 265.714, 266.464, 262.669, 272.063, 272.689, 
-175.62, 225.568, 279.06, -159.431, 216.327, 266.428, 245.597, 
254.043, 254.606, 244.851, 255.798, 257.258, 248.152, 256.508, 
257.622, -319.948, 219.787, 255.769, 243.947, -235.689, -299.64, 
-334.288, 164.071, 230.518, 224.188, 233.409, 234.024, 228.544, 
236.363, 237.405, 235.462, -116.121, -162.999, 240.889, 251.796, 
252.524, 246.8, 258.72, 260.309, 257.726, 267.828, 269.175, 265.087, 
277.995, 278.856, 273.876, 287.09, 288.852, 280.858, 292.608, 
294.174, 246.387, 213.675, 211.494, 201.469, 209.375, 210.429, 
-217.38, -218.456, -218.6, -232.09, 196.612, 225.193, -248.699, 
166.3, 221.633, 213.54, 219.095, 219.836, -261.438, 192.469, 
222.729, -265.48, 164.234, 221.529, -254.99, -254.199, -254.094, 
209.197, -218.172, -246.663, 207.52, -196.823, -250.735, -261.477, 
163.4, 220.05, 210.838, 222.305, 223.069, -196.463, 176.753, 
226.515, 217.024, 249.012, 253.277, 203.798, 226.753, 228.283, 
241.225, 228.683, 227.011, 235.665, 243.606, 244.664, 212.621, 
240.812, 242.692, 207.285, 207.473, 207.498, 194.745, 202.346, 
203.359, 191.408, -221.759, -249.304, 186.022, 192.304, 193.141, 
182.101, 191.751, 193.037, -260.225, 162.901, 191.109, -252.884, 
141.317, 193.877, 186.754, 220.72, 225.249, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 304.742, 0, 316.744, 48.73, 0, 334.833, 0, 
352.419, 54.218, 0, 368.749, 0, 378.178, 31.515, 0, 378.548, 
0, 339.912, 385.233, 406.951, 373.432, 368.963, 411.64, 362.786, 
359.529, 358.897, 353.738, 353.051, 336.054, 340.344, 340.915, 
335.944, 355.461, 356.762, 345.061, 372.321, 375.955, 376.513, 
404.13, 407.812, 416.338, 426.28, 426.943, 432.67, 429.483, 429.058, 
426.368, 425.226, 425.074, 416.298, 411.677, 411.369, 0, 345.327, 
53.127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 183.69, 208.182, 0, 
261.561, 21.797, 0, 298.1, 0, 281.941, 43.375, 0, 314.226, 0, 
304.413, 46.833, 0, 374.171, 0, 368.525, 30.71, 0, 359.118, 0, 
367.905, 56.601, 0, 287.494, 0, 285.213, 43.879, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 735.244, 113.115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 304.619, 0)), row.names = 31537:32536, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: add alpha-value to png-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357926/r-add-alpha-value-to-png-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a way to get the image you want. However, I don't have your original TIFF, and therefore the alignment won't be correct here since I had to use a cut-and-pasted version of the png in your question.

Anyway, the method I would use is:

1. Convert the image to a raster
2. Convert the raster to a `grid::rasterGrob`
3. Plot the rasterGrob as your first layer in ggplot using `annotation_custom`
4. Plot your other layers as normal.

Here's an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rtiff)
library(grid)

x <- readTiff('F01_screenshot.tiff')
pic <- as.raster(array(c(x@red, x@green, x@blue), c(x@size, 3)))
picgrob <- rasterGrob(pic)

ggplot(eet2, aes(x=X, y= Y)) +
  annotation_custom(picgrob) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

You may need to scale your Y axis data to make it match the aspect ratio of the picture.

As an example, if we assume `max(eet2$Y)` is the top edge of the image, and `min(eet2$Y)` the bottom edge, and also assume that `min(eet2$X)` is the left edge and `max(eet2$X)` the right edge (as you have suggested is the case in your comments), we can marry the picture to the data like this:

```r
pic_ratio <- dim(pic)[2]/dim(pic)[1]
data_ratio <- diff(range(eet2$X)) / diff(range(eet2$Y))

eet2$Y <- eet2$Y * data_ratio / pic_ratio
               
ggplot(eet2, aes(x=X, y= Y)) +
  annotation_custom(picgrob) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_density2d() +
  coord_equal(xlim = range(eet2$X), ylim = range(eet2$Y))
```

[image]

If this alignment is not correct, then we need extra calibration information not present in the data (i.e. what value of `eet2$Y` *should* represent the top and bottom of the image, and what value of `eet2$X` represents the left and right edges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a useful beginning. The pic and the plot do not map onto each other 100%. How do I scale the y-axis of the density plot to make it match the aspect ratio of the picture?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I guess that depends. What is it your x and y values represent? It doesn't seem to be pixels (there are negative numbers) - unless they are pixels relative to a specific point on the image? It should be straightforward to marry the picture to the data if you edit your question to include how the numbers relate to the image

Comment: The x and y values represent coordinates of the eyetracker cursor shown as a crosshairs in the picture. That is, the data represent the movements of the participant's eye gaze across her field of vision during a certain time period (the picture shows the last frame from that period)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann co-ordinates in what space though? How are they registered to the picture? Perhaps another way to ask the same question is - what are the maximum possible x and y values, and are these supposed to match the edges of the photo?

Comment: The participant does move her head during the recording thereby moving her field of vision but just slightly so the resulting shift in her field of vision may be negligible. In other words, the maximum possible x and y values would indeed match the edges of the photo

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann but what _are_ the maximum and minimum x and y values? Unless she looked exactly at all 4 edges at some point, we cannot assume that the edges are the same as the max/min of your recorded x and y data points.

Comment: No that 's not what I'm saying. She did not look exactly at the edges. What I'd like to have is a proportional scaling of the x- and y-values to the picture. The maximum **possible** values are the edges of the photo, the maximum **actual** values are a little less.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I _know_ that's not what you are saying, and I know that you want proportional scaling. What I am saying is that in order to have proportional scaling, you need to know the max/min x/y values so that you can marry the picture to the dots. Do you not have these?

Comment: I think I do have them: `max(eet2$X)` and `min(eet2$X)` as well as `max(eet2$Y)` and  `min(eet2$Y)`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann that doesn't seem to be right - your x:y ratio in the data is  1.51 (given by `diff(range(eet2$X))/diff(range(eet2$Y))` ), but the x:y ratio of the picture is 1.761438 (given by dividing the x pixels by the y pixels). Like I said, `max(eet2$Y)` is only the highest point she looked at - not the top edge of the picture (unless she happened to have looked there).

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann if you like I can align the image to max/min eet2 x/y, but I don't think it will be right. You need some way of calibrating the image to the data that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann now updated using your stated correspondence between the max/min X/Y values and edges of the image